# How to bind "OnDataBound" event of "DropDownList" in declarative syntax to a static method in some other class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to bind "OnDataBound" event of "DropDownList" in declarative syntax to a static method in some other class ?

e.g

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="d1" OnDataBound="SomeOtherClassThanThisPage.StaticMethod"></asp:DropDownList>
```

This will give the error, "Page does not contain a definition for SomeOtherClassThanThisPage.

Is this possible to do it like this or it be done in the Code Behind only ?

Comment: i suppose this can only be done via code behind only...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The event handler must be declared in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set your handler in your pageBehind, but in the handler, call the function from your custom class if you are looking to not repeat the same code twice.

Comment: Yes, I want to do this just to have a common piece of code for modifying the items in the dropdown after it is data bound. I know, I can add the handler in the code behind and point it to a custom class's method, but I was looking to do it from the declarative syntax. So that one doesn't need to go to the code behind to see whats happening and search for the ID tag of the drop down there.

Comment: Also these types of things increase the amount of code in the Page_Load event method.

Comment: It shouldn't increase your page_load event method code as the handler is its own stand-alone function.